# reset style inheritance not working in shadow dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm using shadow dom to avoid my element's style from accidently affected by the host document,but it still inheritance some attributes from the parent,like the 'color','font-size','line-height',etc.

After searching google,I have found that there exists one attribute which can be used to achieve this,and it's the 'resetStyleInheritance' attribute.
I use the attribute like this:

```
var root = this.createShadowRoot();
root.resetStyleInheritance = true;
```

or add a 'reset-style-inheritance' attribute the the element,like:

```
<div reset-style-inheritance=true></div>
```

However,both cases didn't work.

I also found a bug report here:[WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103711)

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sangelee/90za0euy/1/

Why the resetStyleInheritance didn't work?Or are there any other solution to prevent style inheritance in shadow dom?Any help is appreciated!

ps.I'm using chrome 39,and just ignore other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `reset-style-inheritance` attribute [is now obsolete](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/attributes/reset-style-inheritance) and should not be used. The shadow DOM is now not to be affected by light CSS anymore by default.

Your code contained an amount of glitches I get rid of (like you were creating the `font-ruler` prior to registering it, and you were handling `attachedCallback` while the proper event to handle is `createdCallback`.) The working version live is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/284au4nw/

A couple comments:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
  createdCallback: {
    value: function() {
      var t = document.querySelector('#s-font-ruler-template');
      this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(t.content);
    }
  }
});
document.registerElement('font-ruler', {prototype: proto});
```

— is appending the template content to your shadow root. You do not need to import node in the existing document (which seems to cheat Chrome and force it to apply light styles... uhm... well... somewhen.)

---

```
<font-ruler></font-ruler>
```

— in HTML is absolutely the same as

```
var font_ruler = document.createElement('font-ruler');
document.body.appendChild(font_ruler);
```

so I tried to keep everything as clear as possible. Hope it helps.

Comment: But in your new jsfiddle,when i add a color style to the font-ruler or the body,`<font-ruler style="color:red;"></font-ruler>` or `<body style="color:red;"></body>`,the shadow element still inheritance the color attribute and cause the text color to be red.

Comment: although the shadow dom's style is not affected by the selectors of the host document,but the shadow dom still inheritance the style of the host document,like color.Any suggestions? @mudasobwa

Comment: You seem to mislead the style inheritance/propagation. Look at the styles inside developer console. You have `body > font-ruler`. The latter, being _a bridge_ between light and shadow DOMs _is not_ shadowed. So, `body`’s style is being applied to it. You are free to set width of the custom element and you are free to set it’s default color. In this case it _derives_ color from `body`. In other words, you are given an ability to change the behaviour of the custom element entirely. By setting `body { color:red}` and/or `font-ruler { color:red}` you are changing the color of the element entirely.

Comment: So my hint would be _not_ to use the document-wide styles at all. It should be considered a good practice in general. Whether you are stuck with 3rd party css or like, simply clear everything by `<style> :host { color: initial }</style>` inside your template.

Comment: The more I think about this case the more I am convinced it’s a wrong approach in spec. The default style for custom element should be **`initial`**, not **`inherit`**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `all` property, it is a replacement for `resetStyleInheritance`